# Matching a file line by line

Tags: regex, perl, for-loop, grep, pattern-matching

```
$text_file = '/homedir/report';
open ( $DATA,$text_file ) || die "Error!";   #open the file
@ICC2_array = <$DATA>;

$total_line = scalar@ICC2_array;    # total number of lines

@address_array = split('\n',$address[6608]);  # The first content is what I want and it is correct, I have checked using print

LABEL2:
for ( $count=0; $count < $total_line; $count++ ) {

    if ( grep { $_ eq "$address_array[0]" } $ICC2_array[$count] ) {
        print "This address is found!\n";
        last LABEL2;
    }
    elsif ( $count == $total_line - 1 ) {  # if not found in all lines
        print "No matching is found for this address\n";
        last LABEL2;
    }
}
```

I am trying to match the 6609th address in `@ICC2_array` line by line. I am certain that this address is in `$text_file` but it is exactly the same format.

Something like this:

`$address[6608]` contains

```
Startpoint: port/start/input_output (triggered by clock3)
Endpoint: port/end/input_output (rising edge-triggered)
```

`$address_array[0]` contains

```
Startpoint: port/start/input_output (triggered by clock3)
```

There's a line in `$text_file` that is

```
Startpoint: port/start/input_output (triggered by clock3)
```

However the output is `"no matching found for this address"`, can anybody point out my mistakes?

Comment: Perl doesn't use `//` for comments.

Comment: How do you check for the failure of `open`? Is [autodie](http://p3rl.org/autodie) enabled?

Comment: Please, paste the real code so we can reproduce the problem. Letting us guess won't probably help you.

Comment: @choroba I have edited it

Comment: Note that arrays are indexed from 0, so `$address[6608]` returns the 660th element.

Comment: @choroba yes i do noticed that and I have printed $address[6608] and it is the address I wan, and I am certain that $text_file has line that contain the same address. And the first element in address[6608] which is address_array[0]. I have also print address_array[0] to make sure it is correct

Comment: You *must always* begin every Perl program with `use strict` and `use warnings 'all'` and declare all your variables with `my` as late in your code as possible.

Comment: `if ( grep { $_ eq "$address_array[0]" } $ICC2_array[$count] )` is usually written `if ( $ICC2_array[$count] eq $address_array[0] )`

Comment: What is in `@address`? How is it populated?

Comment: Your `for` loop is incrementing `$count` with `$count++` as well as your explicit `$count += 1`, so you are examining only alternate elements of `@ICC2_array`. I doubt if that's what you intend?

Comment: @Borodin it's not what I intended thank you for that out

Comment: @Kyle: Have you looked at my answer, which is a much more concise  and clear way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All of the elements in `@ICC2_array` will have new-line characters at the end.

As `$address_array[0]` is created by splitting data on `\n` it is guaranteed not to contain a new-line character.

A string that ends in a new-line can never be equal to a string that doesn't contain a new-line.

I suggest replacing:

```
@ICC2_array = <$DATA>;
```

With:

```
chomp(@ICC2_array = <$DATA>);
```

**Update:** Another problem I've just spotted. You are incrementing `$count` twice on each iteration. You increment it in the loop control code (`$count++`) and you're also incrementing it in the `else` clause (`$count += 1`). So you're probably only checking every other element in `@ICC2_array`.

Comment: Thanks Dave Cross! I have matched the startpoint using your suggestion

Comment: @Kyle: That's good. But please take a close look at Borodin's answer as that shows a far better way to write this code.

Comment: @DaveCross: That's very magnanimous!

Comment: @Borodin: I fixed the immediate problem. You stepped back and took a higher level look at the code.

Answer (score 1):

I think your code should look like this

The `any` operator from core module `List::Util` is like `grep` except that it stops searching as soon as it finds a match, so on average should be twice as fast. Early iterations of `List::Util` did not contain `any`, and you can simply use `grep` instead if that applies to you

I've removed the `_array` from your array identifier as the `@` indicates that it's an array and it's just unwanted noise

```
use List::Util 'any';


my $text_file = '/homedir/report';

my @ICC2 = do {
    open my $fh,'<', $text_file or die qq{Unable to open "$text_file" for input: $!};
    <$fh>;
};
chomp @ICC2;

my ( $address ) = split /\n/, $address[6608], 2;

if ( any { $_ eq $address } @ICC2 ) {
    print "This address is found\n"
}
else {
    print "No match is found for this address\n";
}
```

Comment: it is much more clearer, i tried to use
    List::Util 'any';
any is not exported by the module

Comment: @Kyle: Okay, then you can either install a new copy of `List::Util` or you can just remove the `use` statement and replace `any` with `grep`.